# React Helmet injecting a javascript object into head tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to inject into to head tag a script and link tag which are downloaded from API.
I have variable **injectionScript** which contains the full tag script and **injectionLink** with link tag.
I found that Helmet component accept parameters like src, integrity etc but I need to inject a whole tag.

```
            <Helmet
                script={[
                    {"src": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.21.0/components/prism-swift.min.js",
                        "integrity": "sha512-WkVkkoB31AoI9DAk6SEEEyacH9etQXKUov4JRRuM1Y681VsTq7jYgrRw06cbP6Io7kPsKx+tLFpH/HXZSZ2YEQ==",
                    "crossOrigin": "anonymous"}
                ]}
```

It is possible? I'm trying solutions like this:

```
<Helmet script={injectionScript}>
<Helmet htmlAttributes={{script: injectionScript}}>
```

But doesn't work for me.

**EDIT**: I have only variable const **injectScript = (injectionScript)** This variable is downloaded from API and it just includes a whole tag in one place.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.21.0/prism.min.js" integrity="sha512-WkVkkoB31AoI9DAk6SEEEyacH9etQXKUov4JRRuM1Y681VsTq7jYgrRw06cbP6Io7kPsKx+tLFpH/HXZSZ2YEQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

How to use this variable **injectScript** in Helmet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just have the actual `script` element as a child of the `Helmet` component, like this:

```
<Helmet>
    <script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.21.0/components/prism-swift.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-WkVkkoB31AoI9DAk6SEEEyacH9etQXKUov4JRRuM1Y681VsTq7jYgrRw06cbP6Io7kPsKx+tLFpH/HXZSZ2YEQ=="
        crossOrigin="anonymous"
    />
</Helmet>
```

If you have the attributes of `script` in a variable `scriptAttributes`, you can use the [JSX spread syntax (`...`)](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) as follows:

```
const scriptAttributes = {
    "src": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.21.0/components/prism-swift.min.js",
    "integrity": "sha512-WkVkkoB31AoI9DAk6SEEEyacH9etQXKUov4JRRuM1Y681VsTq7jYgrRw06cbP6Io7kPsKx+tLFpH/HXZSZ2YEQ==",
    "crossOrigin": "anonymous",
}

<Helmet>
    <script {...scriptAttributes} />
</Helmet>
```

Or, to render from a string:

```
const scriptHtmlString = '<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.21.0/prism.min.js" integrity="sha512-WkVkkoB31AoI9DAk6SEEEyacH9etQXKUov4JRRuM1Y681VsTq7jYgrRw06cbP6Io7kPsKx+tLFpH/HXZSZ2YEQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>'

const htmlStrToReactComponent = str => {
    const dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html')
  
    const el = dom.documentElement.querySelector(':not(html):not(head):not(body)')

    const NodeName = el.nodeName.toLowerCase()
  
    const attributes = Object.fromEntries([...el.attributes]
        .map(({ name, value }) => [name, value]))

    return <NodeName {...attributes} />
}

const scriptEl = htmlStrToReactComponent(scriptHtmlString)

// use like this...

<Helmet>
    {scriptEl}
</Helmet>
```

Comment: Yes but If I download this script from API and have injectionScript as variable? How can I put this variable into <Helmet>?

Comment: Ahh, I understand your question now. Edited my answer.

Comment: I have updated question once again, please check :)

Comment: `<Helmet dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: injectScript }} />`

Comment: I tried this solution but it doesn't work, the script doesn't appear on the page, it's not in the Elements tab or in <head>. But if I use console.log(injectScript) it appears in Console. I'm just beginning in React :)

Comment: Re-edited with 3rd way of doing it. If it's still not working, I'd suggest just hacking it together with some regex-based solution or similar.

Comment: For me its almost perfect! One thing thats doesn't work is I download 2 scripts in one const. Only one application is applied for. If there is one tag, it works correctly! :) This may be related to the map function?

Comment: I will leave it as an exercise to the reader to modify for this use case (:

Comment: @LionelRowe does that solution actually work with Helmet?

Answer (score 3):

This was the fix that worked for me, wrapping the string in ``:

```
<script>
{`
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', ${googleAnalyticsId});
`}
</script>
```

Source: https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/334#issuecomment-413319383

Comment: What if I need to use it with outer tag? Like pass <script> to .env and then injecting to head this whole tag, not just content of it